# Bloquear pantalla si no están todos los datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio

He hecho un formulario de registro para una aplicación que introduce los datos en una BD SQL.

```
botonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String usuarioComprobar = campoUsuario.getText().toString();
        String contrasenyaComprobar = campoContrasenya.getText().toString();
        String nombreComprobar = campoNombre.getText().toString();
        String edadComprobar = campoEdad.getText().toString();
        String ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.getText().toString();
        String codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.getText().toString();
        String paisComprobar = campoPais.getText().toString();
        String sexoComprobar = campoSexo.getText().toString();

        if (isNullorEmpty(usuarioComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(contrasenyaComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(nombreComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(edadComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
            isNullorEmpty(codPComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(paisComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(sexoComprobar)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            registrarUsuario();
        }
    }
});

public static boolean isNullorEmpty(String cadena) {
    return (cadena == null || cadena.trim().isEmpty());
}

private void registrarUsuario() {
    UsuariosDbHelper conn = new UsuariosDbHelper(this, "bd_usuario", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.USUARIO, campoUsuario.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CONTRASENYA, campoContrasenya.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.NOMBRE, campoNombre.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.EDAD, campoEdad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CIUDAD, campoCiudad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CODIGOPOSTAL, campoCodPostal.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.SEXO, campoSexo.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.PAIS, campoPais.getText().toString());

    long resultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.NOMBRE, values);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resultado: " + resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Ahora quiero hacer una ventana de logeo que compruebe si el usuario y la contraseña introducidos están en la BD y deje acceder al usuario a la siguiente pantalla. Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede dar alguna pista de como hacer esto.

Se agradece la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas lo puedes hacer con un `Activity` que pase de primero o un `fragment`, como te sientas mas cómodo, el que decidas usar para hacer lo que necesitas hacer seria algo como esto:

Creas el método que hará el `login` de usuario, con esto me refiero al que se ejecutara para validar los campos de ingreso de datos, y en caso de que se introduzcan datos correctos, pase algo, que en tu caso seria consultar esos datos introducidos con tu base de datos, de tal forma que si existen te permitan el acceso. Bien esto seria algo así:

Tomando el ejemplo que te ofrece `Android Studio` para la creación de un `login` sencillo:

```
Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        attemptLogin();
    }
});
```

---

```
private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.

        // ACÁ LA CONSULTA A TU BASE DE DATOS

        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}
```

NOTA: "Ese código completo puedes conseguirlo al crear un proyecto nuevo y selecciones login o en el proyecto que tienes, seleccionas `File > new acitivity > login activity`, de esa forma te crea el `layout` y el  código java"

Bien continuando con lo anterior, al hacer `onClick` llamará al método que realice las respectivas validaciones de los campos, una vez estas validaciones sean exitosas, realizas las peticiones de consulta a tu base de datos, donde hagas la comparación de los datos validos que has obtenido con los ingresados.

Por ultimo y lo mas importante, debes hacer que esta pantalla se muestre primero, como? ordenando el orden de arranque de tu app, colocándola de primero.

En tu caso en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` debes tener algo así:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Tu_actividad"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Para hacer que tu `login` se muestre primero, tendrías solo que cambiar el ese `<intent-filter>` a la actividad con la que desees iniciar. En este caso tu `login`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Quedaría algo como esto,  ya con esto tu `login` se mostrara primero, una vez el ingreso de los datos sea exitoso (cuando los datos se verifiquen y existan). haces un `Intent` para cambiar del `login` a tu actividad a mostrar.

Por lo general y como consejo, podrías crear otra actividad para hacer el guardado de los datos del usuario, algo así como todas las paginas que dicen: "si no tienes cuenta i/o usuario, crea uno aquí", de manera que en el `login` hagas un botón para ir a la actividad de crear usuario guardas los datos del mismo y luego vas a tu `login` e introduces los datos de usuario guardado, para su `verificación` y futuro acceso a tu actividad Home (después del `login` o acción de bloqueo, etc).

Para consultar la base de datos que tienes seria algo como esto:

```
public List<ContentValues> getAll() {
    List<ContentValues> values = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(SQLConstants.TableList,
            SQLConstants.ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues list = new ContentValues();
        list.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.COLUMN_ID)));
         list.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.COLUMN_NOMBRE)));
    }

    return values;
}
```

En ese ejemplo solo recorres y obtienes los valores de tu base de datos, para la comprobación puedes usar un `for` e ir incrementando el valor del cursor en caso de que no coincida el usuario registrado con el que ingresas, y haces esto de forma que cada vez que das clic al botón de `login` revise la base de datos hasta que encuentre tu valor o de lo contrario un error de que no existe. Como dije, es una manera de obtener los valores de base las bases de datos SQLite, puedes emplear la que mas te parezca, pero con esto te doy una idea de lo que debes o podrías hacer.